# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset in array list

Tags: php, warnings, opencart2.x

I add this code in opencart footer controller:

```
    $data['tags_name'] = array('inux','ubunuto','php');
    foreach ($data['tags_name'] as $tag) {
        $data['tags'][] = array(
            'title' => $tag['tags_name'],
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'tag=' . $tag['tags_name'])
        );
    }
```

And add This Line In footer.tpl:

```
<?php foreach ($tags as $tag) { ?>
    <li><a class="" target="" href="<?php echo $tag['href']; ?>"><?php echo $tag['title']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

I check Output:`print_r($tags);` result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => i [href] => http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=product/search&tag=i )
 [1] => Array ( [title] => u [href] => http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=product/search&tag=u )
 [2] => Array ( [title] => p [href] => http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=product/search&tag=p ) )
```

I see Only first word of tags Like: `i` Or `u` Or `p` And see This error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'tags_name' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opencart/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_catalog_controller_common_footer.php

How do can Fix this error and output?!

Comment: Change the `$tag['tags_name']` to just `$tag` ->`'title' => $tag,  'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'tag=' . $tag`. `['tags_name']` is the array key of `$data`, but since you have `foreach ($data['tags_name'] as $tag)` you are already inside the `['tags_name']` key.

Comment: @Sean:Sure U right. work Now

Answer (score 0):

Your array is multidimensional array of arrays.Try like..

```
<?php foreach ($tags as $key=>$value) { ?>
    <li><a class="" target="" href="<?php echo $value['href']; ?>"><?php echo $value['title']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is example:

```
<?php
$arr = array(array('title'=>'i','href'=>'http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=product/search&tag=i'),array('title'=>'u','href'=>'http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=product/search&tag=u'),array('title'=>'p','href'=>' http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=product/search&tag=p'));
//print_r($arr);

foreach($arr as $key=>$value){ ?>
    <li><a class="" target="" href="<?php echo $value['href']; ?>"><?php echo $value['title'];?></a></li>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data['tags_name'] = array('inux','ubunuto','php');
    foreach ($data['tags_name'] as $tag) {
        $data['tags'][] = array(
            'title' => $tag['tags_name'],
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'tag=' . $tag['tags_name'])
        );
    }
?>
```

what is `$tag['tag_name']`?  You can `echo` this and you will find something